# Can I use the concentric conductor of NYCW 95/50 as a ground wire?

Tags: power, grounding

Must one buy a separate ground cable in a TN-S network for earthing or can the concentric conductor be used for earthing purposes?

Comment: In which country is the intended installation?

Comment: The country is Germany

Answer (score 1):

This is how a TN-S earthing system is wired: -

[image]

Image from [TNS Earthing System: A Useful Guide](https://www.linquip.com/blog/tns-earthing-system/).

> *Must one buy a separate ground cable*

If you don't have an earth wire it won't conform to the regulations.

> *can the concentric conductor be used for earthing purposes?*

It has to be exclusively earth and not shared with any other connection like neutral.

Comment: We actually took 4xNYCWY 185/95 cable. It comes with 4 conductors of 185mm2 and 1 concentric conductor of 95mm2. We had given the plan to the energy supplier but I doubt if they carefully looked. 
What is the purpose of concentric conductors in these cables if we cannot use them for grounding purposes?

Comment: I have no idea about that cable or whether some of the conductors can be used for protective earth. I can only tell you what the standard for TN-S is.